# Error while setting up DevOps using Bamboo CICD server

Tags: devops, bamboo

I have successfully installed Bamboo CICD server but while starting the server for the first time itself I am getting an error which says 
"The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program"
I have already set up JAVA_HOME, JRE_HOME and CATALINA_HOME. Also tried all the answers I got from online forums including the Atlassian help forums. Really stuck with this issue. someone who has done this before please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

remove and set all those environment variables once again and it worked.